# Change Path of Config Files in IIS 8

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2

After restarting windows my IIS site can't connect. I get below error:

`FileName:\\?E:\Websites\IISConfig\administration.config`

> Error: The configuration section 'moduleProviders' cannot read because it is missing a section declaration.

I can find the configuration files(`administration, applicationHost, configEncKey`) at default location:

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config\
```

How can I change my IIS site config path from `E:\Websites\IISConfig\administration.config` to `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config\`. If we can't change this path is there a different solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could try below solution to restore the config path.

1.Click on the server in IIS Manager.

2.Scroll down to the "Management" section.

3.Double-click "Shared Configuration"

4.Turn this off to resore to local configuration settings.

---

You could run powershell command to disable the shared configuration.

```
 Install-Module -Name IISAdministration   

Disable-IISSharedConfig
```

Comment: @Brado I can't access any local IIS server or site. Also if I create new server it gives me error:

FileName:\?E:\Websites\IISConfig\administration.config Error: The configuration section 'moduleProviders' cannot read because it is missing a section declaration.

Comment: You could try to use command-line to achieve this. See my update answer.

Comment: Thanks. I will perform this and will update here accordingly.